# Solving fractional differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Is it possible to solve the following equation?

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^\beta}{\mathrm{d}\alpha^\beta}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha}
f(x)+
\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha}
f(x)=\beta\\
\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+
\end{align}

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't like to differentiate with respect to my derivatives.  :(

Comment: I believe this question may be better suited for MathOverflow than regular Math Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about 
\begin{align}
\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+
\end{align}
 but can imagine it working for

\begin{align}
\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_+
\end{align}

I wonder if this can be considered more easily as:

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^\beta}{\mathrm{d}\alpha^\beta}
g(\alpha)+
g(\alpha)=\beta\\
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
g(\alpha)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^\alpha}{\mathrm{d}x^\alpha}
f(x)
\end{align}

Once we have found $g(\alpha)$ we can just integrate repeatedly to find $f(x)$...

The differential equation has auxiliary equation $\lambda^\beta+1=0$, so $\lambda=(-1)^\frac{1}{\beta}$

For $\beta=1$, we have $\lambda=-1$

General solution of homogeneous differential equation is $g(\alpha)=Ae^{-\alpha}$

But we have the non-homogeneous differential equation $\frac {dg}{d \alpha} +g=1$.

Trial function $g(\alpha)=p \Rightarrow \frac {dg}{d\alpha}=0$

So $0+p=1\Rightarrow p=1$

$g(\alpha)=Ae^{-\alpha}+1$